# Colorcoded Terminal with Autocomplete

Tags: command-line

I used to have an Ubuntu installation which, when using terminal:

1. Color coded my input (commands - green, tags - purple, everything else - white).
2. When typing a cmd, would autocomplete, dulled, the cmd based on my history. Pressing right arrow (I think) would fill in the autocompleted cmd for me.

I thought this was default behavior, but recently got a new computer and installed a fresh instance of Ubuntu, and have lost these really useful features. Can anyone tell me what package to install or how to enable them?

Comment: Most likely it was customization made to your `~/.bashrc` file on your old installation ... Look into it if it is still available and if that is the case then simply copy it over to your new installation and next time you open your terminal it will take effect automatically ... Although [this user's .bashrc file](https://askubuntu.com/q/1446961/968501) posted yesterday might contain errors but you will get the idea of how people do it.